# Different bidirectional @ManyToOne parent for 2 Entities extending some base Entity, but keeping base entity data in one table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

This title is closest I could get to what I am trying to do. :)

Let's start with how it should look in database (tables with columns):

```
Email
  - id : PK
  - email : String
CompanyEmail
  - email_id : FK
  - company_id : FK
PersonEmail
  - email_id : FK
  - person_id : FK
Company
  - id : PK
Person
  - id : PK
```

Now let's look at model:

```
@Entity
public class Company
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany
    private List<CompanyEmail> emails = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
public class Person
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany
    private List<PersonEmail> emails = new ArrayList<>();
}

// Should this be @Entity? Maybe @MappedSuperclass? What strategy to use to be able to extend it?
public class Email // This is base email class/entity
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @javax.validation.constraints.Email
    private String email;
}

@Entity
public class PersonEmail // This needs to somehow extend Email, so all Email data is also accessible here.
{
    @ManyToOne
    private Person person;
}

@Entity
public class ComanyEmail // This needs to somehow extend Email, so all Email data is also accessible here.
{
    @ManyToOne
    private Company company;
}
```

Now my question is - is it possible in Hibernate (latest) to achieve such structure?

Key points when designing above (what drove me):

- Keep ALL emails in one table, for sanity checks (uniqueness).
- Have smallest database footprint - above gives just one table for `Email` and then 2 join tables with 2 FK.
- Still be able to keep the model design Hibernate-friendly (basically don't use any special queries, just JPA annotations). This means that both Company and Person can easily LAZY load their specific emails (subclasses), and also those subclassed emails can correspond to them (`PersonEmail` to `Person`, and `CompanyEmail` to `Company`) - making model bidirectional.

Note: I've also considered creating something like `Contactable` base class for `Comapny` and `Person` which would have `Email` list, but that doesn't suit my needs (neither class per table, nor same table designs).

My question is - is it **possible**? Even if I don't get answer with example based on classes I gave, just the fact will give me hope and I will find it.

***Edit 1***

Should I maybe use discriminator in Email table and then keep FK there?

```
Email
  - id : PK
  - email : String
  - companyOrPerson : FK
  - discriminator : Decides what FK points at
Company
  - id : PK
Person
  - id : PK
```

Here I am grabbing straws - I have no idea if such thing is possible, can discriminator decide about parent table (`companyOrPerson`)? Does bidirectional work here (like I mentioned, maybe I should make some base class `Contactable`)?

I am open to suggestions on how to do it well.

Answer (score 0):

Favour composition over inheritence. It tends to simplify things.

If you had main entities of

- Person
- Company
- Email

Then a couple of composites

- PersonEmail   (contains a Person and an Email)
- CompanyEmail   (contains a Company and an Email)

Would that not fit what you need?

e.g.

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="person_id")
    private List<PersonEmail> emails = new ArrayList<>();

}

@Entity
public class Company {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany()
    @JoinColumn(name="company_id")
    private List<CompanyEmail> emails = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
public class Email {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @javax.validation.constraints.Email
    private String email;

}

@Entity
public class PersonEmail {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="person_id",  referencedColumnName="id")
    private Person person;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="email_id",  referencedColumnName="id")
    private Email email;

}

@Entity
public class CompanyEmail
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="company_id",  referencedColumnName="id")
    private Company company;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="email_id",  referencedColumnName="id")
    private Email email;
}
```